# How do I prevent duplicate entries in a row at chosen jQuery multiple select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, checkbox

I have several rows with few select boxes. There are several select boxes in each row with the same content. Every item in the row can only be used once, because every column has a classification. If an item is used in a select box, I want it to be greyed out in the other boxes of the row.
I tried this:

```
  function setChosen() {
    var config = {
  '.chosen-select' : {},
  '.chosen-select-deselect': {allow_single_deselect:true},
  '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
  '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
  '.chosen-select-width' : {width:'95%'}
    }
    for(var selector in config) {
    $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
  }
 }
 setChosen();
 $('.chosen-select').on('change', function() {
   var selVal = $(this).val();
   var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
   $('.'+rel).children('option').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == selVal) {
      $(this).attr('disabled',true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled').trigger('chosen:updated');
  }
 });
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzu66nsa/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

From the select that fires the `onchange` event we can travel up in the DOM to its parent using jQuery's `parent()`. Then select all the `select` elements in that parent. Iterate over each select. First reset the option back to `enabled`, lastly disable the option that matches the selected value of the select that fired the event.

```
 $('.chosen-select').on('change', function() {
    var self = this; //create a reference to the owner of the event.
    var selVal = $(this).val(); //selected value
    var parent = $(this).parent(); //select parent row

    //traverse all children in that row that are selects
    parent.children('select').each(function() {
        $(this).find("option").attr("disabled", false); //set all disabled attributes to false. Basically a reset!
        if (this != self) //skip the select that is the owner of the event
        {
           //set the other options to disabled that matches the value of the select.
           $(this).find("option[value='"+selVal+"']").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it seems that script doesn't work.

Problem is that:

If something is selected in any select box, it may not be selectable in any other box.

-> [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzu66nsa/3/)